# Plotly: how to sum the "text" values displayed on a bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm creating a bar chart in `Plotly Express` and would like to sum the "text" values displayed on the plot.

My data is as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes'],
                          'Dimension':['Styling', 'Styling', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Price', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG'],
                          'Country':['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'England', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Poland', 'Italy', 'USA'],
                          'LowValue':['64', '61', '70', '65', '59', '68', '63', '57', '58', '55', '69', '63', '69', '61'],
                          'HighValue':['82', '95', '93', '95', '87', '93', '85', '85', '95', '92', '83', '87', '80', '80']})
```

I plot this data in `Plotly Express` using the following:

```py
px.bar(df, x='Make', y='LowValue', color='Dimension', 
       barmode='group', text='LowValue')
```

As you can see, the `Styling` bar for Mercedes shows two values:  65 and 64 (because those are the underlying data points).

**Question:  Is there a way to coalesce the underlying data into a single value and only display that single summed up value?**

For example, displaying 129 (the sum of the underlying data points) at the top of the `Styling` bar for Mercedes (instead of displaying 65 and 64).

Comment: Just to clarify do you want to show 64, 65 and 129 on top?

Comment: No, I do not want to show 64 and 65.  I *only* want to show the summed up values at the top of the bars.

Comment: It seems to me that there is not a simple way to do it and that you should play with annotation and offsets for every 'offsetgroup'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas `groupby()` to calculate the total `LowValue` by `Make` and `Dimension` before creating the bar chart:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Make': ['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes'],
                   'Dimension': ['Styling', 'Styling', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Price', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG'],
                   'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'England', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Poland', 'Italy', 'USA'],
                   'LowValue': ['64', '61', '70', '65', '59', '68', '63', '57', '58', '55', '69', '63', '69', '61'],
                   'HighValue': ['82', '95', '93', '95', '87', '93', '85', '85', '95', '92', '83', '87', '80', '80']})

df['LowValue'] = df['LowValue'].astype(int)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by=['Make', 'Dimension'])['LowValue'].sum())

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

fig = px.bar(df1, x='Make', y='LowValue', color='Dimension', barmode='group', text='LowValue')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But in this way you are missing the stacked bars.

Comment: @rpanai - there is no requirement for stacked bars.  In fact, the underlying data contains hundreds of data points for each bar, which would create a mess when you plot it.

Comment: Thank you, @gflavia.  Using groupby() works extremely well.

Comment: @equanimity In this case you should edit your question. From the actual question it looks you want to change the annotation keeping the plot format you used.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that there is a way as long as you are willing to modify your original df

## Data sample

```py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes'],
                          'Dimension':['Styling', 'Styling', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Price', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG'],
                          'Country':['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'England', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Poland', 'Italy', 'USA'],
                          'LowValue':['64', '61', '70', '65', '59', '68', '63', '57', '58', '55', '69', '63', '69', '61'],
                          'HighValue':['82', '95', '93', '95', '87', '93', '85', '85', '95', '92', '83', '87', '80', '80']})

# we better use int here
df[["LowValue", "HighValue"]] = df[["LowValue", "HighValue"]].astype(int)
```

## Arrange Data

Now you want to have sum for `LowValue` but as you want to display only one you need to play a bit

```py
df["LowValueSum"] = df.groupby(["Make", "Dimension"])["LowValue"]\
                      .transform(sum)

# Here we consider the latest index within the goupby only 
df["idx_max"] = df.groupby(["Make", "Dimension"])["LowValueSum"]\
                  .transform(lambda x: x.index.max())

df.loc[df["idx_max"] != df.index, "LowValueSum"] = np.nan

# now you can eventually drop the previous colums
# df = df.drop("idx_max", axis=1)
```

## Plot

```py
fig = px.bar(df, 
             x='Make', 
             y='LowValue',
             color='Dimension', 
             barmode='group',
             text='LowValueSum',
             hover_data={"Country":True,
                         "Dimension":False,
                         "Make":False},
             hover_name="Dimension")
fig.update_traces(textposition="outside")
```

[image]

**Update** Given that `182` looks really close to the upper range you can eventually add this line

```py
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, df["LowValueSum"].max() * 1.2])
```

Comment: In barmode = 'overlay', How to show the labels for each individual bars and also to show the Total at the top?

Comment: @sumantadas have you consider to open a different question? Please post a link here then.

Comment: here is the link of the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72761553/how-to-display-the-total-sum-of-the-values-at-top-of-the-stacked-bar-chart-along

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to display text over bar chart. I have created sample visualisation using plotly express as follows:

```
# Text Position Outside Bar Chart
import plotly.express as px
percentage = [64,24,12]
category = ['Category_A','Category_B','Category_C']

fig = px.bar(x=category, 
             y=percentage,
             text = [str(round(i,2))+'%' for i in percentage], # text to display 
             labels={
                     "x": "Category",
                     "y": "%Percentage",
                 },
                title="Category Distribution in Dataset")

fig.update_traces(textposition="outside") # text position - outside the bar chart

fig.show()
```

[image]

```
# Text Position Inside Bar Chart
import plotly.express as px
percentage = [64,24,12]
category = ['Category_A','Category_B','Category_C']

fig = px.bar(x=category, 
             y=percentage,
             text = [str(round(i,2))+'%' for i in percentage], # text to display 
             labels={
                     "x": "Category",
                     "y": "%Percentage",
                 },
                title="Category Distribution in Dataset")

fig.update_traces(textposition="inside") # text position - inside the bar chart

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the y arrow to open the options, then select cumulative sum. The next row will show the added values, and the last entry will be the total sum.